# Export all polygons to SVG using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, svg, centroids

For a game, I needed to draw the districts of my city in QGIS. I created a layer and drew many polygons on it.
I have now a table with four columns, being "fid", "name" and "lon" and "lat".

How can I export each of them to SVGs with only their other lines drawn?

I have seen heaps of articles about exporting an entire layer or to PDF or including styling, but nothing for my purpose.

Is there an easy way to do that?

[image]

Comment: For your first question see https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/7199/107424. It works the same for all types of geometries. Then you can focus on your second question ;)

Comment: Thank you, this actually worked! I rewrote the question to focus on the svg one

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312242/export-as-svg-with-path-polygon-ids

Comment: @BERA I followed that guide and now have one layer for each polygon, but I fail to export this. I have a button "New print layout" which gives me a white page, how do I get my svgs in there?

Comment: How about creating and atlas that generates a page for each feature, then export that to SVG

Comment: I don't get it. I go to the atlas function in the printing menu, click on "generate an atlas", choose the coverage layer being my polygons, pagename being fid and deactivate "single file export". It then exports me the map with all of my polygons n times, one for each polygon, but always the same map with all of them